# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format (swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I want to take weather informations with JSON but there is an error : **The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.**

Error 'It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.' in stackoverflow. Although I briefly describe my problem, it still expects an explanation from me :/

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=bursa,tr&appid=00f63a1cff271776651468c0204c422c"
            getData(from: url)
        }
        
        private func getData (from url : String){
           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!, completionHandler: { data , response , error in
                guard let data = data ,  error == nil else {
                    print ("birşeyler ters gitti")
                    return
                }
            var main : Response?
                do {
                    main = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self , from: data)
                } catch{
                    print ("ERROR IS HERE!!! \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                guard let json = main else {
                    return
                }
            print (json.weather)
                })
            task.resume()
        
        
        
    }}
        
    struct Response : Codable {
               let weather : myResult
               let status : String
               
           }
    struct myResult : Codable {
               let main : String
               let description : String
               let icon : String
           }
```

API Response is like that :

```
{"coord": { "lon": 139,"lat": 35},
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 281.52,
    "feels_like": 278.99,
    "temp_min": 280.15,
    "temp_max": 283.71,
    "pressure": 1016,
    "humidity": 93
  },
  "wind": {
    "speed": 0.47,
    "deg": 107.538
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 2
  },
  "dt": 1560350192,
  "sys": {
    "type": 3,
    "id": 2019346,
    "message": 0.0065,
    "country": "JP",
    "sunrise": 1560281377,
    "sunset": 1560333478
  },
  "timezone": 32400,
  "id": 1851632,
  "name": "Shuzenji",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: Replace `error.localizedDescription` with `error` in the `catch` block. Now you get a meaningful error message about the Decoding error.

Comment: @vadian I already had it prepared to include in my answer. Somehow I just forgot to update it. Thanks for reminding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `error.localizedDescription` is meant to display an information for the user. It's not useful for debugging. If you replace it with `error`:

```
} catch {
    print ("ERROR IS HERE!!! \(error)") // <- remove .localizedDescription
}
```

you will get more details:

> ERROR IS HERE!!! typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>,
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue:
> "weather", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode
> Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError:
> nil))

To solve this you need to declare `weather` as an array:

```
let weather: [myResult]
```

I'd also recommend replacing `myResult` with `Weather` (or at least capitalised `MyResult`) as it will be more readable:

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    let main: String
    let description: String
    let icon: String
}
```

Also, in the JSON response you provided there is no `status` field so you may need to remove it from the `Response` class (or make it optional).

If you'd like to add more fields to the response, declare them according to your JSON structure. Eg. if you want to add `humidity` and `temperature` you can do:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    ...
    let main: Main
}

struct Main: Codable {
    let temp: Double
    let humidity: Double
}
```

To have a more readable code you can use `CodingKeys` - then your variable names can be independent from JSON variables.

```
struct Main: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temperature = "temp"
        case humidity
    }
    
    let temperature: Double
    let humidity: Double
}
```

Summing up, your `Response` may look like this:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let weather: [Weather]
    let main: Main
    // alternatively declare `status` optional
    // let status: String?
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    let main: String
    let description: String
    let icon: String
}

struct Main: Codable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temperature = "temp"
        case humidity
    }
    
    let temperature: Double
    let humidity: Double
}
```

Comment: thank you... now our result is  [Hava_Durumu.myResult(main: "Clear", description: "clear sky", icon: "01n")].       how can I reach just 'main' or 'description' ?  print (json.weather.main) dont working

Comment: @E.YILDIRIM `weather` is an array (a collection of elements) which means you need to access a specific element. Eg. if you want to access the first element in the weather array you can use: `json.weather[0].main`

Comment: Then how can I add humidity and temp values ? Its giving an error like that : The data couldn’t be read because it is missing.

Comment: @E.YILDIRIM See my updated answer - remove `.localizedDescription` and you will get more details.